# Does a service worker compete for bandwidth?

Tags: html, offline-caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

A service worker installs in the background, while the page is loading.

1) Does downloading of the service worker script happen in parallel with page load and delay the load?

2) Do the assets mentioned in install event get downloaded and cached in parallel with page load, or after page load event finished

3) Does caching of assets respect the HTML Native cache, or are they redownloaded every time?

Answer (score 3):

First time around, the service worker will be fetched when you call register. For update checks, the browser does this per navigation, but waits until after load to avoid competing with the page.

Answer (score 2):

A service worker has a lifecycle which is completely separate from your web page.

- A service worker is run in a worker context: it therefore has no DOM access, and runs on a different thread to the main JavaScript that powers your app, so it is not blocking. It is designed to be fully async; as a consequence, APIs such as synchronous XHR and localStorage can't be used inside a service worker.
- Service worker has its own lifecyle. Typically during the install phase, you'll want to cache some static assets. If all the files are cached successfully, then the service worker becomes installed.
- Sure, browsers cache stuff all the time. The advantages here are in persistence and control. Browser caches are easily overwritten while an application cache is more persistent. Badly configured servers often force the client to refetch things unecessarily, for example hosting providers you don’t have control over. Service workers, with a full caching API, allow the client full control, and can make smarter decisions about what and when to cache.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but this doesn't answer any of my doubts. My question is clearly relating to competing bandwidth with currrent page, not blocking rendering.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Does downloading of the service worker script happen in parallel with page load and delay the load?

Downloading the service worker happens once you call [`register()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register) and it does it in parallel and thus, it **does not delay** the load.

> 2) Do the assets mentioned in install event get downloaded and cached in parallel with page load, or after page load event finished.

Any network request originated within the Service Worker **does not block** the main thread nor the document load.

> 3) Does caching of assets respect the HTML Native cache, or are they redownloaded every time?

Requests originated withing a service worker honor the native cache ([http cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching_FAQ)) but [you can modify this behavior with the `cache` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch#Parameters) if you want.

From questions, it seems you think that registration from a Service Worker is coordinated with the document load but **it's not**. Once called `register()` or after a service worker update found, all the stages for registering the service worker are decoupled (and run in parallel) from the web page load.

Comment: Thanks. When I said "interfering with document load" I actually meant interference with the bandwidth, not page rendering. Anyway, I got the answer.

Comment: If you think I answered your questions, consider marking my answer as the solution.

Comment: Does that mean it will also make network request for precache resources and we can have two calls for same resources on first page load ?

Comment: Yep. The first one, not intercepted by the sw and the second one, originated in the sw. But, the second one probably won't reach the network for it will hit the http cache which is in between the sw and the actual network.